# Already initialized constant Patientinfo::PATIENT_HASH. warning: previous definition of PATIENT_HASH was here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a concern patientinfo with following code

```
module Patientinfo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    PATIENT_HASH = {
      '0' => 'Test1',
      '1' => 'Test2',
      '2' => 'Test3',
      '3' => 'Test4'
    }.freeze

    def patient_map(patient_number)
      PATIENT_HASH[patient_number]
    end
  end
end
```

Now when i start the rails server i am getting the error in title. 
Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you're not defining that variable somewhere else? or are you using 'active_admin'?

Comment: PATIENT_HASH is defined only in Patientinfo concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're including this module in more than one class, included will run the same block again, re-defining the constant, hence the collision. Do you include this module in more than one class?

Comment: Yes. i am calling it in 2 separate models

Comment: then this is the issue. The constant is already defined by the time the second class includes this module.